# How to setup python-pulsar with apache

Tags: python, django, python-pulsar

Trying to work with [Django python pulsar](http://pythonhosted.org/pulsar/tutorials/django.html#tutorials-django) concurrent processing framework.

The wsgi server provided by `pulsar` can be used through command line as

```
$python manage.py pulse
```

which basically starts a HTTP WSGI server, similar to django's dev server.

How can it be set up with Apache webserver with mod_wsgi?

Answer (score 0):

Is this case what you really want is to use pulsar's WSGI server and consume your django app as a regular wsgi application (if you are on django 1.5.x or above it would have created a wsgi.py in your project home). Here's an example:

```
from pulsar.apps import wsgi
import yourapp

middlewares = [
    wsgi.middleware.wait_for_body_middleware,
    yourapp.wsgi.application
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wsgi.WSGIServer(wsgi.handlers.WsgiHandler(middleware=middlewares)).start()
```

protip: the "wait_for_body_middleware" makes pulsar wait for the full body response to be available before moving on to another request (which is the normal behavior of most webapps)

source:

http://pythonhosted.org/pulsar/apps/wsgi/intro.html#wsgi-server